# Is there a way to mark file as "being worked on"?

Tags: git, github

For the first time I started using git with a team and I'm not yet comfortable with merges that require manual resolution. I wonder if there's a way to mark a file as "being worked on" so that everyone could see it and move on to work on something else.

Comment: If you're going to do that, you might as well use RCS.

Comment: "I'm not yet comfortable with merges that require manual resolution" Best plan is to get comfortable. Merge conflicts are not bad things and are not difficult to deal with. Github gives you great tools for resolving merges, or you can do it in the comfort of your own machine with whatever tool you like. In most cases direct editing of the text is simplest, actually.

Comment: If you regret doing the merge, you can just abort it and think it over. There is really no need to mark any files as needing anything, though. Things being worked on, on the branch you intend to merge to, in such a way as to cause a merge conflict, are simply a fact of life when you're on a team. Get used to it.

Comment: Resolving merge conflicts is not harder or more complicated than crossing the street. Plus there's somewhat less chance of bloodshed and medical bills. What's not to love?

Comment: > *I'm not yet comfortable with merges that require manual resolution* That ship sailed decades ago with CVS and whatnot.

Comment: `Move on to something else` ?? What if something else also touches the same file? Its better to learn to deal with merge conflicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in a decentralized VCS (Version Control System) like Git, which don't have that feature natively.

Only Git hosting services can add additional feature like this.
GitLab proposes [file locking](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/file_lock.html) as a way to show other collaborators a file is being worked on.